# Speed bumps on public ways illegal in Massachusetts?

Tags: traffic

I had the recollection that it was illegal in Massachusetts to have speed bumps in public ways, however, on searching the laws today I could find no statute to that effect.

Is there such statute? Am I misremembering it? Was there once such a statute and now it has been removed?